# How to hide data and reveal it in a smart contract

Tags: privacy, zksnark

I know the topic has already been discussed but I did not find any satisfying answer. Do you know a way to put some private data in the blockchain and release / reveal it to a designated personn.

I know about zk proof but from my understanding its purpose is to prove something without revealing it. I want to hide data (a password) and revealing layer when a condition is met.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use a commit-reveal scheme. "A" sends to "B" some bytes using symmetric encryption. At some point A reveals to B the password to decrypt those bytes. Once decrypted, the new bytes turn out to be information again encrypted (this time with asymmetric encryption) with B's public key, so that only B with his private key can read it. The transmission of the password doesn't necessarily need to be made through the blockchain, though. It can simply be sent offline.

Comment: Thank you for the Quick answer. Here is what I want to do :  I have an encrypted file outside blockchain. I want my smart contract to escrow the decryption key as trustlessly as possible. And release/reveal it to the beneficiary when a condition is met. With your solution how do I hide the password on thé blockchain and reveal it later

Comment: Exactly as I said. You can send any string of bytes you want with this method, it's just a bit more confusing because you'd be using a second password to encrypt the actual file's password.

Comment: I understand but the password to decrypt the bytes  Can I stock it somehow hidden in the smart contract. And then reveal it when a condition is met.

Comment: You can't "hide" anything on the blockchain, not even marking the attribute as private. The only way is to store information encrypted with different mechanisms, like the one I mentioned.

Comment: Oh ok I see ! I'm going with this then, thank you !

Comment: No worries, I'm happy to help! Good luck!